# Timer not working in app

Tags: android, timer

I have written schedule task by using timer. It is working fine withing single activity.But when i am going to another activity it is not working.My intention is to send data to the server  some particular time interval. I am giving the code snippet. I am sorry for the format.

private void login() 
    {

```
    try {
        EditText userNameET = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.userName);
        EditText passwordET = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.password);

        String userName = userNameET.getText().toString();
        String password = passwordET.getText().toString();

        boolean isLoginOK = isValidUser(userName, password);
        String autoSynchStrVal = "";
        String autoSyncFreqStr  = "";
        long autoSyncFreqInMiliSec = 3600000; // default 1 hrs

        if (isLoginOK) {
            //added by anirban
            CommonUtils.IS_NEW_VERSION_AVAILABLE = isNewVersionAvailable();
            CommonUtils.IS_NEW_Notification_AVAILABLE = isNewNotificationAvailable();

             autoSynchStrVal = CommonUtils.getPolicyValue(appInstance, "IS_MOBI_AUTO_SYNCH_REQ", 0, 0);


             if(autoSynchStrVal != null && !"".equals(autoSynchStrVal) && "1".equals(autoSynchStrVal)){
                 //boolean isAllTransactionsUploaded  = false;
                // boolean isAllTransactionsUploaded = VersionCheckingActivity.isAllTransactionsUploaded();
                // boolean isMobiEligibleForAutoSync = UploadDownload.isMobiEligibleForAutoSync(appInstance ,isAllTransactionsUploaded);

                //  if(isMobiEligibleForAutoSync){
                 autoSyncFreqStr = CommonUtils.getPolicyValue(appInstance, "MOBI_AUTO_SYNCH_FREQUENCY", 0, 0);
                 if(autoSyncFreqStr != null && !"".equals(autoSyncFreqStr)){

                     autoSyncFreqInMiliSec =  (long) (Double.valueOf(autoSyncFreqStr) * 60 * 60 * 1000); // in millisecond
                 }




                /* boolean isMobiEligibleForAutoSync = false;
                 try {
                     isMobiEligibleForAutoSync = UploadDownload.isMobiEligibleForAutoSync(appInstance ,
                             VersionCheckingActivity.isAllTransactionsUploaded());

                     if(isMobiEligibleForAutoSync){
                         _doSynch();
                     }

                    } catch (UDBAccessException e) {
                      e.printStackTrace();
                   } */




                     myTimer = new Timer();
                     myTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            ULoginActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    // here we are checking again for eligibility for auto synch
                                    boolean isMobiEligibleForAutoSync = false;
                                     try {
                                         isMobiEligibleForAutoSync = UploadDownload.isMobiEligibleForAutoSync(appInstance ,
                                                 VersionCheckingActivity.isAllTransactionsUploaded());

                                         Log.d("inside Run : ", "before Synch");

                                         if(isMobiEligibleForAutoSync){
                                             _doSynch();

                                             Log.d("inside Run : ", "after Synch");
                                         }

                                    } catch (UDBAccessException e) {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }


                                }
                            });

                        }
                    },  1000, autoSyncFreqInMiliSec); //here interval is autoSyncFreqInMiliSec




             }


            endAction(RESULT_LOGIN_OK, null); // it will finish the activity
        } else {
            // showing login error
            TextView login_msg = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.login_screen_msg);
            login_msg.setTextAppearance(this, R.style.error_msg);
            //login_msg.setTextColor(Color.RED);
            login_msg.setText("Login failed.");
        }
    } catch (UDBAccessException e) {
        UUIHandlers.showErrorMessage(this, e.getMessage());
    }catch (Exception e) {
        UUIHandlers.showErrorMessage(this, e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this happen when you switch to another activity on your app, or to another application?

Comment: To another activity.My intention to send data to server in background some particular time interval. any idea regarding that.

Answer (score 0):

If you hold your timer in a field of your activity (`Activity` subclass) it will probably go away once you launch another activity. Consider moving your timer to service (`Service` subclass). This will hold your timer going regardless of your activity flow.

Read this for reference about services:
https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html

Answer (score 0):

To make it work when you leave the `current activity`, you have to run that code of snippet on the `background service`.

As you are executing on the current `Activity` it runs the code for the first time, but as you leave the `activity` the code wont **be triggered itself unless it is registered to a `background service`**.

[Here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_services.htm) and [here](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidServices/article.html) you have examples on how to use them

Answer (score 0):

If you want to execute something after some time, even when your activity is not currently in the foreground, you can use the [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html).

> Note: The Alarm Manager is intended for cases where you want to have your application code run at a specific time, even if your application is not currently running. For normal timing operations (ticks, timeouts, etc) it is easier and much more efficient to use Handler.

If you want to periodically send information to a server, I suggest you use a [Service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) or an [IntentService](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html).

> A Service is an application component representing either an application's desire to perform a longer-running operation while not interacting with the user or to supply functionality for other applications to use.

You can find a good example using a LocalService also [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#LocalServiceSample).

Answer (score 0):

Finally got the solution .
Now from Async task( different thread), You are trying to insert data in the database which is locked by UI thread. This will throw an exception because the first write has a lock on the db.